# how to create a desktop application in order to have multiple firefox browser

Tags: python

I need to automate the work done by the firefox profile manager. With this application the users choose the navigator, for example, firefox browser and the number of profiles that he wants to create then press the button to create [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmUeZ.png)

To create a firefox profile manually we execute the command firefox.exe -p in order to open the firefox profile manager I tried to execute the command with python using the function subprocess.run but it didn't work.

Comment: Share you efforts.

Answer (score 0):

This is already part of Firefox, accessible by [command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options). You can run `firefox -silent -CreateProfile newprofile`.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer it works in terminal but how can i run the command with python i did subprocess.run("firefox -silent -CreateProfile newprofile", shell=True) but it didn't work for me